# WP8.0 and WP7.1 project namespace issue C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, namespaces, windows-phone-7.1

I have a problem with *namespaces*. I wrote four *Windows Phone* 7.1 project (*XNA* game) and after that I added a *Windows Phone* 8.0 project (*XAML*) to the solution.

I would like to start the game after the *XAML* launched up and the user clicked on the "start game" button. When I add the *XNA* project as a reference to the *XAML* project and using it in the *MainPage.xaml*, I get an error:

> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'liveBodyVisualization' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does this mean they can't communicate because of the different Windows Phone versions? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try adding the namespace in your .cs? This error says that you're missing a reference.

Comment: Yes, but didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with different versions of Windows Phone. This is an issue with one project not being able to "see" part of the code referenced by the other project.

I'm assuming that the `liveBodyVisualization` namespace is either in your code or some third party library that you've included. This is not visible to the project that is raising the error.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to add those references, it says, I can't do that because of the version differences.